# unicode string modification failing

Tags: swift, unicode

I am trying to tokenize a string with unicode characters. I am having trouble removing unicode tokens from the front of the string. I have tried

```
 code = String(code[prefix.endIndex...])
```

and

```
  let range = code.index(code.startIndex, offsetBy:0)..<prefix.endIndex
  code.removeSubrange(range)
```

Non unicode tokens (in prefix) are removed correctly.  For example with code = "a + b" and prefix = "a". Both statements return " + b". However 
with code = "← a + b" and prefix = "←" both of the above statements return code as;

```
 "\u{86}\u{90} a + b"
```

The goal is to remove the ← so the output should be;

```
 " a + b"
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your input and what is your desired output logic, but `offsetBy: 0` means you set the offset manually and may cause unicode breaking.

Comment: The input are strings of  symbols and words. As each one is recognized from the front of the string, it should be removed. Non unicode substrings are being removed correctly, but unicode ones are not.

Comment: `code.index(code.startIndex, offsetBy:0)` is exactly the same as `code.startIndex`. Btw you can NOT use an index from a different string

Comment: So you want to remove characters one by one from the beginning of the string?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a playground

Comment: Strings don’t have “Unicode tokens”. How the string was input as a literal is irrelevant. ← is just a character like any other.

Comment: I am writing an interpreter for expressions which include non-standard operators from a special font. I defined the token set and I am matching them with reg-exes. As each token is matched, I remove it from the string and repeat until the string is empty. The code above works on all tokens except operators like the arrow and other special characters in the font.

Answer (score 0):

Use native unicode compatible version of character remover instead:

For removing and returning first element:

```
let justFirst = code.removeFirst()
```

For removing the first and return the remaining characters

```
let allButFirst = code.dropFirst()
```

Similarly for the `last` character:

```
let justFirst = code.removeLast()
let allButFirst = code.dropLast()
```

Also you can convert it to standard `Array` and then work with that if you are happy with arrays:

```
let array = code.map { $0 }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for single character tokens only.

Comment: Make a loop then. Do you need help for that?

Comment: ahah. good one. in fact I'm already doing that now. I'm just wondering why the code above doesn't work.

Comment: Witch code? Feel free to ask for further help if need any.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to tokenize the string. You can remove whatever characters you want from the resulting array `tokens`.

```
func testTokenization() {
    let input = "← a + b"
    var tokens: [String] = []
    for character in input {
        tokens.append(String(character))
    }
    print(tokens)
}
```